# Integrate deeplearning4j with JHipster Maven pom.xml, getting SLF4J binding error

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jhipster, deeplearning4j

I tried to integrate deeplearning4j with JHipster pom.xml with the following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and I'm getting the following error while I run .\mvnw :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/william/.m2/repository      /org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.6/slf4j-nop-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/william/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at   org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a    Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/william/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class  ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:346)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLogger(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:215)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.aitrader.AitraderApp.main(AitraderApp.java:64)
    ... 6 more
```

as you can see I have added exclusions on deeplearning4j already, but I still getting SLF4J binding conflicts, couldn't finger out what's the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `mvnw dependency:tree` and searched for duplicate dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I still can't finger out duplicate SLF4J. By the way I used JHipster 3.x with spring boot 1.3.5.RELEASE.

Comment: Hi, Can you file an issue on the dl4j repo? https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues I thought we had taken care of the logger dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finger out the problem by using m2eclipse in eclipse by selecting Dependency Hierarchy tab instead of 'mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j', and found out 'org.neuroph' has a duplicate 'slf4j-nop' the following pom.xml section should be:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j.version}</version>

       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>

    </dependency>

   <!-- ND4J backend. You need one in every DL4J project. Normally define artifactId as either "nd4j-native-platform" or "nd4j-cuda-7.5-platform" -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>${nd4j.backend}</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neuroph</groupId>
        <artifactId>neuroph-core</artifactId>
        <version>${neuroph.version}</version>
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```